# Game with hourly rewards

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, cron

i want to make a web-based game for my study.

The game is simple: after registration you have 100$ and you can buy let's say one tree, this tree will give you 10 apples per hour and you can sell one apple for 1$

My question is: how do i make this tree drop 10 apples per hour? Do I need to write another C# Console programm (aka cronjob) that connects to database and updates everything? Catching users, gettings their trees and giving them apples every hour? I have tried it that way but it is a performance issue

I have tried to do that and filled my database with dummy 1000 users and each user had 10000 trees (so 10000000 trees in total) but my C# program (so-called cronjob) is taking more than 5 minutes to reward all fake players with apples

I am using entity framework and foreach loop to catch every player and count their trees then add apples to them and save database changes

Comment: This sort of job should be carried out by the db not in code. Most current RDBMS have some sort of scheduler.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane How do I do that in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Create a stored procedure to update the appropriate data. Then have the SQL Server Agent fire the SP every hour. See this for info on the Agent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @BarryO'Kane i have also one more question about sql, i want to add more stuff through admin panel (for example i want to add tree that gives nuts) how do i force my sql command to search for all possible trees and their possible rewards? or do i have to update my stored procedure code every time when i add new tree?

Comment: That depends. If you hardcode the values into the stored procedure you will have to update it every time. But if you have a lookup table that holds the tree type and reward, you can have the SP use it to determine how to multiply out the rewards.

Answer (score 0):

First, if a request to your server is the only way anyone can see apple count updates, I don't see the need to make those updates before the next request. You can store latest_apple_drop_datetime, and on request, calculate how many times apples were dropped and when the most recent drop was. That way you don't need any cronjob. Next, does a player see other players' activity? If not, you have to process only the requesting player's trees. Finally, look into implementing all updates in a single UPDATE statement (I assume you are using an SQL database), without any loops in your code, letting the database itself optimize performance

Comment: Hi, I want everyone to see other player's apples and other stuff, so I think cronjob is needed.. thank you for your information